# how to align expandable list view button?

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I created expandable list view application. The application is working fine; my issue is my expandable view click button.  It is not in the center of the list view.  How do I show the center of the screen. The text is centered, but the button is at the bottom bottom of the screen. This is a problem...

This is my xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  
      android:orientation="vertical"   
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"  
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      >  

      <ExpandableListView   
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"  
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"   
        android:layout_weight="0"  

        android:id="@+id/ExpandableListView">  
      </ExpandableListView>  
    </RelativeLayout>
```